# Using customized ami in AWs CloudFormation Template

Tags: aws-cloudformation

While using customized AMI in cloud formation template , system rechability check fails , since /etc/sysconfig/network is configured with hardcoded hosname and /etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-etho has hardcoded ip . If we use Aws cloud formation init to change these values its not reflecting. How can we achieve this changes ?

Comment: Can you post what your template looks like? What's your UserData look like? Are you calling cfn-init correctly?

Answer (score 0):

In order for [`AWS::CloudFormation::Init`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html) metadata to actually result in changes on your instance, you need to execute it by running the [`cfn-init`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-init.html) helper script.

Also note that since you're using a customized AMI, [`cfn-init`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-init.html) and the rest of the `cfn-helper` utilities may not be installed - they are preinstalled only in the latest Amazon Linux AMI, as noted in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-helper-scripts-reference.html). For Ubuntu or any other distribution you need to install them manually, which you can do by adding a line to your EC2 instance's user-data script (using an Ubuntu AMI and `apt-get` as an example):

```
UserData:
  "Fn::Base64":
    !Sub |
      #!/bin/bash -xe
      apt-get update && apt-get install pip && pip install https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest.tar.gz
      /usr/local/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource MyEC2Instance --configsets do_install --region ${AWS::Region}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is that the AMI you have your networking interfaces set to "STATIC"
You should update the AMI's network script to use DHCP so it will obtain a new IP from the subnet that it is placed in.

Like @wjordan said, you can always use the "User-data" property to do extra configuration and also query the machines Instance MetaData to query the info you need IP/HOST etc

http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4